# clEnqueueReadBuffer failed: out of resources

Tags: python, opencl, gpgpu, raytracing, pyopencl

I'm having trouble trying to do a ray tracing program with pyopencl.

To give you some context, the idea behind the program is that i have a inicial set of photons in a grid and they only have momentum on the z component. They go through a lenses with a space-dependent refraction index. After a few time intervals I try to build an histrogram with the positions of the photons

For this purpose, i've used numpy and pyopencl. I start with arranging the photons in a array with this format: [[X0,Y0,Z0,Kx0,KY0,KZ0], ..., [XN,YN,ZN,KxN,KYN,KZN]] where 0 -> N is ths index of the photon. And then I passed this numpy array to the device to so the calculations which are a simple integrations of a linear system with Runge Kutta 4th order.

My code attempt was the following:

***Python Main***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
from pylab import *


if __name__ == "__main__":

# Photons grid
Lx = 1.0
Ly = 1.0
delta_x = 0.01
delta_y = 0.01
Nx  = Lx / delta_x
Ny  = Ly / delta_y

X,Y = np.mgrid[-Lx:Lx+delta_x:delta_x,-Ly:Ly+delta_y:delta_y]
X = X.ravel()
Y = Y.ravel()
Z = -10.0

Kx = 0.0
Ky = 0.0
Kz = 1.0

N_points = len(X)

# Arranging the initial photons on a grid to send to Device in form of [[X0,Y0, ...], [X1,Y1, ...], ....]
grid_h = []
for i in range(N_points):
    grid_h.append(np.array([X[i], Y[i], Z, Kx, Ky, Kz], dtype=np.float32))
grid_h = array(grid_h)


# Time Parameters
Lt = np.float32(1.0)  # Time interval between departure of the photons and arrival at the "screen"
delta_t = np.float32(0.1)  # Time step
T = np.arange(0.0, Lt, delta_t)


# Device Init
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
MF = cl.mem_flags

# CL Source Read and Build
f = open("kernel_tracer_2.cl", "r")
Source = f.read()
prg = cl.Program(ctx, Source).build()

# Constant init
N0 = np.float32(1.0)
Nm = np.float32(0.05)
C0 = np.float32(3.0)
DR = np.float32(0.2)

# Execution; Sends Blocks of photons to device, evolves them step by step
grid_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=grid_h)
for t in T:

    # Evolve every photon
    time = np.float32(t)
    prg.RK4Step(queue, grid_h.shape, None, time, delta_t, N0, Nm, C0, DR, grid_d)

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, grid_h, grid_d)
X = grid_h[:, 0]
Y = grid_h[:, 1]

# Plotting
figure(1)
plt.plot(X,Y,'.')

figure(2)
H, xedges, yedges = histogram2d(X,Y, bins=50)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax.set_title('imshow: equidistant')
im = plt.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest', origin='low',
                extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])

show()
```

***Device Code*** (kernel_tracer_2.cl)

```
float8 f(float t, float N0, float Nm, float C0, float DR,
     float8 q)
{ 



const float ind = N0 + Nm * exp(-(q.s0*q.s0 + q.s1*q.s1 + q.s2*q.s2)/(DR*DR));
const float np = sqrt(q.s3*q.s3 + q.s4*q.s4 + q.s5*q.s5);
const float c1 = C0 / (ind * np);
const float c2 = -2.0 * C0 * Nm *exp(-(q.s0*q.s0 + q.s1*q.s1 + q.s2*q.s2)/(DR*DR)) / (ind * ind * DR * DR);
float8 v;

v.s0 = c1 * q.s3;
v.s1 = c1 * q.s4;
v.s2 = c1 * q.s5;


v.s3 = c2 * q.s0;
v.s4 = c2 * q.s1;
v.s5 = c2 * q.s2;

return v;
}


__kernel void RK4Step(float t, float dt, float N0, float Nm, float C0, float DR, __global float8 *p){
const int gid = get_global_id(0);
float8 k, qm,qs;


//k1
k = f(t, N0, Nm ,C0, DR, p[gid]);
qs = p[gid] + dt * k/6.0;
qm = p[gid] + 0.5 * dt * k;

//k2
k = f(t+0.5*dt, N0, Nm ,C0, DR, qm);
qs +=  dt * k/3.0;
qm = p[gid] + 0.5 * dt * k;

//k3
k = f(t+0.5*dt, N0, Nm ,C0, DR, qm);
qs +=  dt * k/3.0;
qm = p[gid] + dt * k;

//k4
k = f(t + dt, N0, Nm ,C0,DR, qm);
qs +=  dt * k/6.0;

//update photon
p[gid] = qs;
}
```

whenever i run the code i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path here", line 73, in <module>
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, grid_h, grid_d)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopencl-2014.1-py2.7-win-       amd64.egg\pyopencl\__init__.py", line 1090, in enqueue_copy
return _cl._enqueue_read_buffer(queue, src, dest, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: clEnqueueReadBuffer failed: out of resources
```

Line 73 is: cl.enqueue_copy(queue, grid_h, grid_d)
That being when i try to copy the calculations results back to the device.

Now the thing is. I get this error on my GTX970. I tried this code in a Titan and it runs ok until i change delta_x and delta_y to something lower than 0.01. On the other hand i tried to run the code on my laptop with an old Mobility Radeon HD 5145 and it runs great. I know it's a different SDK but this gets me confused. 
I have also tried to change both delta_x and delta_y to 0.1 just to test it, and i get no errors but the results are all wrong, when compared to the Titan and my laptop's results.

I have both the latest drivers and sdk from nvidia.

I'm sorry for the long post but i've been trying to figure this out and have no idea what could be causing this. I've tried to post all the info I think it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is your problem but from looking at this, you should wait for your RK4 step to finish before copying your result:

```
prg.RK4Step(queue, grid_h.shape, None, time, delta_t, N0, Nm, C0, DR, grid_d)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, grid_h, grid_d)
```

Instead do

```
completeEvent = prg.RK4Step(queue, grid_h.shape, None, time, delta_t, N0, Nm, C0, DR, grid_d)
events = [ completeEvent ];
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, grid_h, grid_d, wait_for=events);
```

Or call `completeEvent.wait()`. Your kernel call isn't blocking and so isn't guaranteed completion, yet you copy your results out. That can lead to interesting (incorrect) behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I changed it to call completeEvent.wait() and with delta_x and delta_y = 0.05 it changed the output to something more similiar to what i was expecting. 
Yet with both delta = 0.01 i get this error now: clWaitForEvents failed: out of resources when i call completeEvent.wait(). I have no idea what this could be.